# HMS : alternative for CampaignTrackingReceiver of Google analytics in Huawei DTM Kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Is there any alternative for **CampaignTrackingReceiver of Google analytics in Huawei DTM Kit**?
Currently, I'm following below link of Google analytics :
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/CampaignTrackingReceiver

Also unable to find any Huawei Kits for replacement of "fireBase-appindexing:19.1.0", Can anyone suggest some useful information or any document link.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm following below link of Google analytics : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/CampaignTrackingReceiver

DTM don't has similar class, for this question, you don't need to config Receiver in AndroidManifest.xml. Huawei Analytics SDK will auto-collect information of install_referre when user open app for the first time. We don't have similar class in Huawei analytics too. [Reference Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-automatic-event-collection-0000001051757143#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001055544428__li1902124561120).

> Also unable to find any Huawei Kits for replacement of "fireBase-appindexing:19.1.0"

For app index, you can use app linking. Even google also recommends app linking instead of app indexing, so you could try using Huawei [App Linking](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction-0000001054143215).

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the tag template-based visual event tracking feature of DTM Web to report events in your website to Google Analytics. Here are some info. and one example for your reference:

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0202575663223170066?fid=0101187876626530001

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/web-visual-event-tag-ha-0000001151584240

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/tracing-point-development-0000001078556280

As for app index, you can refer to Huawei app linking :

Developer Guide: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction-0000001054143215

Codelabs: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelabsPortal/searchdetail?searchKeyword=App%20Linking

[image]

Manually Constructing a Link of App Linking: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-createlinks-defined-0000001055514692